# Mistakenly put wrong year on resume, would it affect my background check?

Tags: job-search, resume, job-offer, hiring-process, background-check

After accepting an offer and submitting the background check report, I was notified by the immigration team that there is a discrepancy in the employment history I entered in the immigration questionnaire and my resume. I checked my resume and noticed that I accidentally put the wrong year on my current job. My current job starts on **July 2021** but I put **July 2020** there and didn't notice this typo for a very long time.

I was working at the current company as an intern 6/2020 - 9/2020, and then joined the company I'm applying to as a contractor 12/2020 - 6/2021. Then I left there and worked at my current company from 7/2021 to now. Now I'm planning to rejoin that company as a full-time employee. I didn't want to hide anything as it's pretty clear that those work experiences are overlapped.

I remembered that I entered the right employment history when filling the online application, and I told my hiring manager that I was in this team until Jun 2021. Some of my interviewers are actually my previous coworkers and they know clearly that I was there last year instead of at my current company.

I sent the clarification email to my on-boarding HR but haven't heard back from her yet. Do people think this will cause me to lose my offer? Shall I contact my recruiter and hiring manager immediately to explain this?

Comment: Side note: your resume is one of the most important documents you will send around. It's good a idea to triple check the data and have someone else proof read it. Typically I'm not a stickler for this type of thing but as a hiring manager I cant help thinking "If you are sloppy even if it's on your own interest to pay attention to detail, how I can expect you not to be sloppy at work ? "

Comment: @Hilmar Thank you! I will double-check every important document in the future. This is a lesson for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I sent the clarification email to my onboarding HR but haven't heard back from her yet. Do people think this will cause me to lose my offer?

You did the right thing, and clarified on the first chance you got. It is unlikely this will cause you to lose the offer, unless they are unreasonable or very picky about these things.

> Shall I contact my recruiter and hiring manager immediately to explain this?

Yes your could, this would be an additional step that would help, so both your recruiter and HR aware of this.

The things that are on your favor are that the dates overlap, suggesting a typo and not ill-intentions, and that some of the people involved already know you.

Let the process continue, be open and clarify any other possible doubts, and hopefully everything will proceed as if the typo didn't happened.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate your answer. I think I might enter the right year when submitting my job application since that info on my applicant profile is correct. So I will wait and see what the background check result comes out.

Answer (score -1):

I have found some that look at the resume purely as a marketing document and some that look at it as a legal contract and evidence.

I would use situations like this to filter out employers with toxic and hostile hiring practices.  If this is a significant big deal to this company, what is it going to be like working under that management culture day-to-day.